# Google OAuth 2.0 Service Account Authentication

Tags: php, google-app-engine

How Google Service Account can be authenticated using PHP?
Here are the references-
1. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/aaa_oauth2_service
2. https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/service-account.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple thing.
Get the .p12 file from the Google Cloud Console.
Put the CLIENT ID, EMAIL ADDRESS and .p12 NAME in the https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/service-account.php .
Then you will get the right service.